# aspnet-sessionId not working for Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nlog

I am migrating an ASP.Net application to ASP.Net Core. Principally setting up NLog works fine as expected. 
Now I want to log the session id together with the log message. For that I added 
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session
- NLog.Web.AspNetCore
from NuGet.

Sessions are activated in Startup and I get Session IDs in the code.

Following [NLog on GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues/153) in the `Startup.cs` one should add

```
//add NLog.Web
app.AddNLogWeb();
```

which doesn't make any sense because the method is marked obsolete.

However, neither with that line nor without it NLog produces correct output to the logfile. Only the following is logged:

```
2018-12-03 09:59:42.6111 Warn Exception in layout renderer. Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext.get_Session()
   at NLog.Web.LayoutRenderers.AspNetSessionIdLayoutRenderer.DoAppend(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
   at NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer.RenderAppendBuilder(LogEventInfo logEvent, StringBuilder builder)
```

The target configuration looks like this:

```
    <target archiveAboveSize="10000000" 
        xsi:type="File" 
        fileName="${basedir}/logs/SystemOut.log" 
        archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/SystemOut_${shortdate}.{#}.log" 
        archiveEvery="Day" 
        archiveNumbering="Rolling" 
        maxArchiveFiles="50" 
        layout="[${date:format=dd\.MM\.yyyy\-HH\:mm\:ss}] [${level}] [${callsite}] [${aspnet-sessionid}] [Client:${event-context:item=clientId}] [User:${aspnet-user-identity}] Url: ${aspnet-request-url} Action: ${aspnet-mvc-action} ${message} ${exception}" 
        autoFlush="true" 
        name="sysout" />
```

And here is the content of `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

What is missing in my configuration?

Comment: this has instructions on how to setup session after adding nuget. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1#session-state

Comment: Maybe my description was misleading. With _Sessions are activated_ I meant that app.UseSessions() is called.

Comment: You might have followed the wrong getting started guide, because the section for asp.net core 2 does not contain a `app.AddNLogWeb();` call. See: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2.
I have also updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

Your question also indicates, that you might be following the wrong "getting started" guide, since calling `app.AddNLogWeb();` is only applicable for Asp.Net Core **1**, while you are most likely using version **2**. Please refer to the correct sections of the documentation:

- [Getting Started on Asp.Net Core 2](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2)
- [Getting Started on Asp.Net Core 1](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-(csproj---vs2017))

**Original Answer**

The error is pretty self explantory. You have not configured your application to use sessions.

In your `Startup.cs` - `ConfigureServices()` method, add the following line:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     /*other config...*/
     services.AddSession();
}
```

Then add the following in the `Configure()` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseSession(); //<--- add this line
    app.UseHttpContextItemsMiddleware();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

This should resolve the exception.

And here is the explanation in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Maybe my description was misleading. With Sessions are activated I meant that app.UseSessions() is called. So unfortunately this is not a solution.

Comment: please read carefully. I am not unsing AddNLogWeb(). This method is obsolete. I just mentioned that it doesn't work with or without the call.

Comment: I have not said, that you used it, but that you might have used the wrong getting started guide and thus may follow the wrong instructions, because `AddNLogWeb` does not exist in the most recent instruction set.

Answer (score 2):

If the recommended method of calling `UseNLog` in `Program.cs` is completely impossible:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#4-update-programcs

Then you can also do this:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Web;

public class Startup
{
  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSession(); // After AddMvc()
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
  }

  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
    app.UseSession();  // Before UseMvc()
    app.UseMvc();
    app.ApplicationServices.SetupNLogServiceLocator();
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();
  }
}
```

See also http://www.jiodev.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state

Comment: NLog itself works as logger. The only problem is that `${aspnet-sessionid}` won't be evaluated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check to put in the Startup.cs

```
// Configure Method
app.UseRouting();


// AppService Method
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddSession();
```